# Catch or change browser error messages in safari

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari

We have an app that allows a user to download files. If an I-device user doesn't have a reader (like ibooks) installed, safari gives a default message of (Safari cannot download this file).

My issue is that I'm attempting to change this message to something more useful. However, I'm striking out on a way to catch or interact with the safari error. Standard things like catching all errors in javascript (window.onerror) do not work. 
Does anyone have an ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that's possible without writing a plugin for Safari, and even then I don't know that it's possible. The problem is that the error isn't generated by the page - it's generated by the browser application which is running on the users computer - so no code that you write is going to be able to intercept that because there is no action between the page and the browser once the user clicks that link.

In broad strokes, here's what happens:

1. User loads URL, server sends out HTML.
2. User clicks link
3. Server sends file, browser tries to render
4. Browser detects that there is no application installed
5. Browser throws error

You'll see that here is no interaction between the server and the user after step 3.

You MIGHT be able to detect that the iBooks app isn't installed, but I don't know how you'd go about doing that.